# Is there step by step tutorial on creating bayesian network?

Tags: bayesian-networks

I'm looking for tutorial on creating bayesian network. I have theoretical information and background but I would like to see it in practise on some real-life example.

Could you recommend me some such tutorial? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is an online course called "Probabilistic Graphical Models" by Stanford professor, Daphne Koller:

https://www.coursera.org/course/pgm

Click on "Preview" to watch the past lectures.

The Stanford course page is here, with a link to the textbook:

http://pgm.stanford.edu

Answer (score 0):

You can see a step by step example on how to create one @ http://unbbayes.sourceforge.net/video_tutorial.html. This is a link to video tutorials that explain how to use UnBBayes, an open source tool for modeling Probabilistic Graphical Models, most related to Bayesian Networks.

One of the videos from the link above is the youtube video @ https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=ExlfjBQfvMk, which explains how to create a BN step by step using UnBBayes.

Cheers,
Rommel

Comment: Can you post some relevant content from the link?

Comment: I added more information about one of the videos inside the first link. Was that what you were looking for?